# I can't stop the "+" sign in my R console

Tags: r

I can't run any of my commands because the "+" sign keeps showing up on my R console.  I have tried the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but neither is working. Please I need help with this. Here is the command I am trying to run.

```
initial_hare_population <- 300000

Hn <- initial_hare_population

Hn <- 300000

initial_lynx_population <- 1500

Ln <- initial_lynx_population

Ln <- 1500

pop_Hn <- c(300000)

pop_Ln <- c(1500)

timesteps <- c(1)

generations <- seq(1, 500)

for (generation in generations) {
  delta_Hn <- delta_H(r1, Hn, Ln, d1)
  delta_Ln <- delta_L(r2, Hn, Ln, d2)
  Hn <- Hn + delta_Hn
  Ln <- Ln + delta_Hn
  pop_Hn <- append(pop_Hn, c(Hn))
  pop_Ln <- append(pop_Ln, c(Ln))
  timesteps <- append(timesteps, c(generation))
}
```

I tried <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but neither has worked.

Comment: This isn't reproducible: we don't have `delta_H` or `delta_L`: 'Error in delta_H(r1, Hn, Ln, d1) : could not find function "delta_H"'

Comment: The `+` on the console is often/usually indicative of an incomplete previous expression. This could be due to unmatched parens/brakes/brackets or perhaps other parsing problems with the code. Your code _here_ does not evidence that, so I don't know that we'll be able to help much if at all. (I'm a bit surprised, though, since even with mismatched parens/..., a `Ctrl-C` should terminate that.)

Comment: Who closed this as a typo?

Comment: @jay.sf I sometimes dislike the limited scope Stack uses for closing questions. For instance, "not reproducible" (which seems to be applicable here) and "typo" (not clear in this code) are not always interchangeable. Having said that, it can easily be that the `+` line-continuation occurs due to a typo, so both reasons given in this closure _might_ be applicable. Either way, unless/until OP is able to update the question, it is clearly not reproducible.

Comment: I think, "This question was caused by a typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers." is just not applicable here, it "needs debugging details" @r2evans

Comment: I don't disagree, and I think there can be overlap between close-reasons. (I also think that if the list of close-reasons included "press any key", people would choose that. Many times I think people would prefer a reason "don't care" or "prefer not to say, I just want it closed", though that would be hurtful. I also get frustrated when somebody new to Stack asks a question and then immediately disappears, not realizing the plummeting chance of success after the first hour. Lots of things here that could be improved.) This is perhaps why many have a negative new-to-Stack experience. @jay.sf